# Rendering Word document without word

Tags: pdf, ms-word, rendering

Are there any solutions for Rendering MS-Word 2003 Documents (WordML) into PDF without MS-Word? I found Aspose.Words which seems good but has some problems. Is there any other solution out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use OpenOffice. It reads and writes Word documents and can save documents as PDF.

Another solution might be is [Altsoft's xml2pdf](http://alt-soft.com/Products.aspx)

Comment: Produces too much errors in the File I'm trying to render. This file contains all Word 2003 features and most of them are quiet useful.

Answer (score 0):

[Antiword](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=1&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.winfield.demon.nl%2F&ei=7msuSraZC43BtweG0935Cw&usg=AFQjCNFJgBpGwQFcCAJ-BzrYVGem43sdPg). I used this awhile ago to have a Linux web app read MS Word documents and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Consider [ZamZar](http://www.zamzar.com/).

On-line file conversion between many file formats: Upload the source file specifying target file type and an Email address; receive the converted file in your inbox.

Comment: Online conversion is not possible. The company policy forbids this.